# Native way to run a forEach loop on an unnamed JSON object

Tags: jmespath

Example JSON

```json
[
  {
   "id": 12,
   "clientName": "super-client"
  },
  {
   "id": 15,
   "clientName": "helloClient"
  }
]
```

I want to use JMESPath to check if each clientName field does not contain the text `super-` and then display the result

I'm using the API connector tool for Google Sheets to parse a JSON I get via a call. I'm stuck with this.

Almost all the reference examples on JMESPath site have a named object or array. This JSON I have doesn't have any named objects.

I want to do something like

```
result = []
for entry in data:
if not entry['clientName'].find("super-"):
result.append(entry)
return result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JMESPath, it is called a [*filter projection*](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#filter-projections) and it can be applied on an array right away, without it having to be named.

What you will need on top of a filter projection is the [`contains`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains) function and the [*not* expression `!`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#not-expressions).

All this together gives you this query:

```
[?!contains(clientName, 'super-')]
```

Which, on your JSON example will give, as a result:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 15,
    "clientName": "helloClient"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! this works and yours is cleaner than what i did.  
So as an extension of this, how do I add multiple search strings in the contains function? 

I tried the following   

`[?![contains(clientName, 'super-') || contains(clientName, 'Man')]]`

  
But i'm getting a blank worksheet with this. Where have I gone wrong in the syntax? 
For the purpose of this additional question, assume there's another object with   `clientName = "SpiderMan`

Comment: No need to have an extra square bracket there: `[?!contains(clientName, 'super-') || contains(clientName, 'Man')]`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function test() {
  var json = [
    {
      "id": 12,
      "clientName": "super-client",
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "clientName": "helloClient",
    }
  ]
  var result = json.filter(e => e.clientName.includes('super'))
  console.log(result)
}
```

```js
  var json = [
    {
      "id": 12,
      "clientName": "super-client",
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "clientName": "helloClient",
    }
  ]
  var result = json.filter(e => e.clientName.includes('super'))
  console.log(result)
```